# How to remove EventListener that is in a function?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have 3 event listeners in a function, I would like that once the user has clicked the event would be removed but can be called later on. Here is my code:

```
//Event Listeners
function listeners(nextPage) {

    function good() {eventGood(nextPage)}
    function mild() {eventMild(nextPage)}
    function bad() {eventBad(nextPage)}

    function eventGood(page) {
        x = 1;
        rightText = answerOne.innerHTML;
        bb = "goodAnswer";
        page();
    }

    function eventMild(page) {
        x = 2;
        rightText = answerTwo.innerHTML;
        bb = "mildAnswer";
        page();
    }

    function eventBad(page) {
        x = 3;
        rightText = answerThree.innerHTML;
        bb = "badAnswer";
        page();
    }



    answerOne.addEventListener("click", good);
    answerTwo.addEventListener("click", mild);
    answerThree.addEventListener("click", bad);


}
```

Where do I add my:

```
answerOne.removeEventListener("click", good);
answerTwo.removeEventListener("click", mild);
answerThree.removeEventListener("click", bad);
```

Inside the function or in the global context once one of them has triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it in the functions themselves.

```
function good() {
    eventGood(nextPage);
    this.removeEventListener("click", good);
}
function mild() {
    eventMild(nextPage);
    this.removeEventListener("click", mild);
}
function bad() {
    eventBad(nextPage);
    this.removeEventListener("click", bad);
}
```